# Granting permissions to a DB user - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, users

I need to grant select and update permissions to a DB user (TestUser) on TestDB database as per below.

[image]

When I press ok and re-check the permissions, they are not visible as can be shown below:

[image]

From my testing, only permissions at object level (e.g. columns, etc) are displayed here.

Can select permission on the **database** be visible from somewhere apart by executing T-SQL code? Is this a bug or by design? The same applies to user defined DB role permissions and it is very misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason you are not seeing the permission when you open the window by default it is scoped to `Securable scope: Schema' and not`database`.

[More on secureables.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/securables?view=sql-server-2017)

> Can select permission on the database be visible from somewhere apart
>   by executing T-SQL code?

Yes it is possible. From your 2nd screen:

- Click Search...
- Select radio button `All objects of the types....`
- Click `Ok`
- Select `Databases`

You should see `TestDB` in the list at top half of the window. In the bottom half you can see Explicit and Effective permission.

In case you want to use tsql:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'testuser';  
USE [DbaDatabase];  
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE');  
REVERT;
GO
```